# How do I access the router setting page on a D-Link router when the gateway has been changed to an IPv6 address?

Tags: ipv6, gateway, adsl-router

My D-Link router model DSL-2750U default gateway has been changed to an IPv6 address

Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.248.5(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%15

How do I access the router setting page? I have tried resetting it multiple times but thee values do not change.

Comment: You tried entering the default gateway in your browser?

Comment: Is hard resetting the router an option?

Comment: @spykyvenator Yes I tried fe80::1%15 this default gateway since ipv6 the browser understands ipv6 address as [fe80::1%15] but yet that didnt help.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek i have tried hard resetting it multiple times but to my luck it keeps giving me ipv6 as default gateway.

Comment: I wonder if its just faulty then. It happens - and if you can't reset it, there's not much you can do.

Comment: My internet provider doesn't let me access the settings page with the default gateway (for some mysterious reason) my modem was installed by the same company that provides internet. If that's the problem you should find some manual from them or you might want to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to 192.168.1.1 in a browser.  That is the default default gateway.

The 169.254 address is an APIPA(Automatic private IP address) address that a device will auto assign itself if it can't get an IP address from a DHCP server.

Comment: I tried 192.168.1.1 & also 192.168.0.1 none of them work